# PHP Adding Curl to function which uses file_get_contents

Tags: php, curl

I am having problems enabling `file_get_contents` on my site. It was suggested I could use curl instead.

This is my original function, using `file_get_contents`:

```
function getFile($fileQuery){
  global $user, $pass, $domain;

  return file_get_contents("https://$user:$pass@$domain:2083/".$fileQuery);

}
```

And this is what I tried, using curl:

```
function getFile($fileQuery){
  global $user, $pass, $domain;

  //return file_get_contents("https://$user:$pass@$domain:2083/".$fileQuery);

  $url = "https://$user:$pass@$domain:2083/".$fileQuery;
    $ch = curl_init();    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1); // return into a variable  

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,0); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 4000);    //timeout in seconds

    $result = curl_exec($ch);  
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($result);  
    curl_close($ch); 


}
```

However, it's returning a blank page.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use curl instead of file_get_contents in the following way:

```
   $url = "https://$user:$pass@$domain:2083/".$fileQuery;
    $ch = curl_init();    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1); // return into a variable  

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,0); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 4000);    //timeout in seconds

    $result = curl_exec($ch);  
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($result);  
    curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm updated my question...please see main question. Tried adding this code to the function but getting a blank page.

Comment: Can you please provide me full url https://$user:$pass@$domain:2083/".$fileQuery
i mean what the value of $fileQuery here so that i can test and  fix your problem.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not allowed to give the site url here. I understand if you can no longer help me because of that.

Comment: Step 1. if(curl_errno($ch)){
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
  }
use this block of code this will print exactly what the error is or 

Step 2. you can give a dummy url of a any webpage which returns data if it returns that means there is a problem in your url.